# Determine if collision occurred in C++11 unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11

I am playing around with C++11 and I am trying to add elements to an unordered set and if I already added an element to my unordered_set I don't want to add it again (i.e.) don't add cat again to the unordered set below.

```
    std::unordered_set<std::string> s;
    std::vector<std::string> myString;

    myString.push_back("cat");
    myString.push_back("dog");
    myString.push_back("bird");
    myString.push_back("cat");



for(auto &i : myString){
        //add elements from myString to unordered_set s
}
```

I am not exactly sure how to do this. I realize that I need to have a `std::pair` equal to my `s.insert(i)` however I'm not quite sure how to set this up so I can do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Why are you concerned? `std::unordered_set` only contains unique elements (automatically doesn't add if it already exists), but there is a `find()` function:

```
for(auto &i : myString){
    if(s.insert(i).second) 
        //inserted
    else
       //already exists
}
```

Comment: How do I get it to return the bool value about whether the element was added?

Comment: @user2604504 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert
check the return value if insert

Comment: @balki yeah I was trying to do it like (1) but I was a bit confused on the syntax for my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(auto& i: myString) {
    if(s.insert(i).second) std::cout << "inserted" << std::endl
    else std::cout << "dupe" << std::endl;
}
```

`unordered_set` won't insert duplicates, no checks required.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) contains a set of *unique* objects.

This means that it can *not* contain duplicates (two elements are considered equivalent if `operator==` returns true).

**Example:**

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> s;
s.emplace("cat");
s.emplace("cat");
s.emplace("cat");

// At this point s only contains one std::string object.
```

To add unique items from a `std::vector` simply use [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) like this:

```
s.insert(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

A `std::unordered_set` will not insert an element if it already contains an element with an equivalent key.